# Python - excel - xlwt: colouring every second row

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

i just finish some MYSQL to excel script with xlwt and I need to colour every second row for easy reading.

I have tried this:

```
row = easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour blue')

for i in range(0,10,2):

ws0.row(i).set_style(row)
```

Alone this colouring is fine, but when when I write my data rows are again white.

Can some please show me some example 'cuz I m lost in coding :/

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only ever applied color to rows using the `write()` method.
Does something like this work for you? (adapted from [this excellent example](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/examples/xlwt_easyxf_simple_demo.py)):

```
mystyle = easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour blue')

for row in data:
    rowx += 1
    for colx, value in enumerate(row):
        if rowx % 2 == 0:
            # apply style for even-numbered rows
            ws0.write(rowx, colx, value, mystyle)
        else:
            # no style for odd-numbered rows
            ws0.write(rowx, colx, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [the answer to your identical question in the python-excel google-group](http://groups.google.com.au/group/python-excel/browse_frm/thread/578015ccf8ec76bc?hl=en#).